# CSS Grid Layout TextBox not spanning multiple columns

Tags: css, width, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grid Layout and am having difficulty in trying to make a TextBox fill the div container it is in.  It seems to work fine for some controls such as GridView / GoogleMap, but when I try with a TextBox it only fills the width of one column, even if the div is filling up 3-4 columns.

Here is my sample CSS for the grid-container and what I am using to fill all columns

```
.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    -ms-grid-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
    .grid-container {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20em, 1fr));
        -ms-grid-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20em, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
}

.item-max-columns {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

This GooleMap Control displays correctly across all columns filling the screen (GridViews also display correctly)

```
<div class="item-max-columns">
    <map:GoogleMap ID="JobMap" Width="100%" runat="server" DefaultAddress="Edmonton, Alberta"></map:GoogleMap>
    <map:GoogleMarkers ID="JobMapMarkers" TargetControlID="JobMap" runat="server"></map:GoogleMarkers>
</div>
```

However when I try to insert a TextBox with width 100% it only fills one column

```
<div class="item-max-columns">
    Project Description
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectDescription" runat="server" Enabled="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle that reproduces the problem with input fields instead of TextBox.  I would like the input field / TextBox to span the whole div tag not just the first column.

https://jsfiddle.net/zuvdx2xn/

[CSS Width Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvym0.jpg)

Comment: Please post enough code so the problem can be reproduced.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by updating CSS to include

```
.textbox{
    width: calc(100% - 2em);
}
```

and input/textbox control to

```
<input type="text" id="txtVal2" class="textbox" style="max-width: 100%;" />
```

```css
.grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    -ms-grid-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1em;
}

.textbox{
    width: calc(100% - 2em);
}

@media (min-width: 52em) {
    .grid-container {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20em, 1fr));
        -ms-grid-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20em, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
    .textbox{
      width: calc(100% - 2em);
    }
}

.item-max-columns {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid-container">
  <div class="item-max-columns">
    <p>Project Description</p>
    <input type="text" id="txtVal2" class="textbox" style="max-width: 100%;" />  
  </div>
  <div class="item-max-columns">
    <p>Instructions</p>
    <input type="text" id="txtVal2" class="textbox" style="max-width: 100%;" />  
   </div>
</section>
```